# Error converting data type varchar to numeric vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms

When i'm trying to insert data to database it's getting error called "error converting data type varchar to numeric"

This is my code

```
objcon.DoExecute("INSERT INTO OrderItemF 
                  VALUES('" & dgOrder.Item("Item No", i).Value & "'
                         ,'"& dgOrder.Item("Item Type", i).Value & "'
                         ,'" & txtOdrNo.Text & "'
                         ,'" & dgOrder.Item("Unit Price", i).Value & "'
                         ,'" & dgOrder.Item("Quantity", i).Value & "'
                         ,'" & dgOrder.Item("Discount", i).Value & "'
                         ,'" & dgOrder.Item("Total Value", i).Value & 
                        "')"
                       )
```

i'm inserting data from a data grid viewer called dgorder

Comment: it means some column is expecting a numeric and you are passing text - `txtOdrNo.Text` looks like it might be a number, convert it using `Convert.ToInteger` or `Integer.TryParse` depending on what it is and where it came from. the others look like values but you are converting them to string by using the ticks

Comment: You would probably be better off abandoning the `objcon.DoExecute` method and using SQL Parameters to pass the values with the SQL query.

Comment: ...and I suspect you are opening the connection once and keeping it open. That isn't the recommended way; instead, open connection, execute query, close connection.

Comment: I tried converting string to integer,but still i'm getting a error saying "value cannot be null.Parameter name:String"  This is my coversion ('" & System.Int32.Parse(dgOrder.Item("Total Value", i).Value) & "')

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is when you do

```
"'" & dgOrder.Item("Unit Price", i).Value & "'"
```

your query will look like `'value'` for numerics. But for numerics you don't want single quote. So what you need to do is to remove single quote where you have numeric value.

This is your database complaining - "I expect integer and you giving me a string"

**EDIT**

My original answer resolved your insert issue. Now, you need to do some more work about your `null` values, your possible single quotes in data and conversion of text to `null`

```vb
dim itemNum as string = dgOrder.Item("Item No", i).Value ' assume it is string
itemNum  = If(string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemNum), "NULL", "'" & itemNum.Replace("'", "''") & "'") 

dim itemType as string = dgOrder.Item("Item Type", i).Value ' assume it is string
itemType = If(string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemType), "NULL", "'" & itemType.Replace("'", "''") & "'") 

dim orderNum as string = If(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtOrdNo.Text), "NULL", "'" & itemType.Replace("'", "''") & "'") 

dim decVal as Decimal
dim intVal as Decimal
dim unitPrice as string = If(dgOrder.Item("Unit Price", i).Value, "") ' assume it is decimal
if Decimal.TryParse(unitPrice, decVal) Then
    Throw New Exception("Invalid Unit Price")
Else
   unitPrice = decVal.ToString()
End If                 

dim quantity as string = If(dgOrder.Item("Quantity", i).Value, "") ' assume it is integer
if Integer.TryParse(unitPrice, intcVal) Then
    Throw New Exception("Invalid Quantity")
Else
    quantity = intVal.ToString()
End If          

dim discount as string = If(dgOrder.Item("Discount", i).Value, "0") ' assume it is decimal
if Decimal.TryParse(discount, decVal) Then
    Throw New Exception("Invalid Discount")
Else
   discount = decVal.ToString()
   ' may need: discount = If(decVal = 0, "NULL", decVal.ToString())
End If 

dim total as string = If(dgOrder.Item("Total Value", i).Value, "") ' assume it is decimal
if Decimal.TryParse(total, decVal) Then
    Throw New Exception("Invalid Total Value")
Else
   total = decVal.ToString()
End If                          

dim sql as String = String.Format("INSERT INTO OrderItemF VALUES({0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6})",
    itemNum, itemType, orderNum, unitPrice, quantity, discount, total)

objcon.DoExecute(sql)
```

This is more like programming

Comment: I tried removing the single quote.it's works for me.But now i'm getting another error message saying invalid syntax near ","

Comment: @Randz90 Put breakpoint on your `objcon.DoExecute`. Once it breaks, copy your statement `"INSERT INTO OrderItemF...."` into intermediate window [of cource, use `?` in front]. Press enter. See what is the output. I suspect that one of your columns returns `nothing`. So what you need is to use `if(<val>, <val if nothing>)`. `<val if nothing>` should be `"NULL"`. But then, if your field is string, you need to add your single quotes within `If()`. But lets first test your statement and post output of it.

Comment: @Randz90 I did replacement on your insert and I got this: `INSERT INTO OrderItemF VALUES('x','x','x','x','x','x','x')`. This is a valid statement. So, you, may be didn't remove quotes properly, you have strange value coming out of your grid. Or this is not caused by this statement? You need to do what I said in the previous comment first. The Error you getting now is about badly formed sql statement. So, before modification your statement was OK but DB complained. Now your statement is bad.

Comment: @Randz90 another thing is your string data in the grid may have single quote in it `'`. Then this will cause this error. You need to do `val.Replace("'", "''")` - replace all single quotes with 2 single quotes. This is why it is good idea to use parametrized query - you don't have to deal wit these things and better performance on DB.

Comment: @ T.S. I tried to run the query by putting a break point.Like you said before all the values passing from data grid are strings.How am I convert this string values into decimal. '" & Decimal.parse(dgOrder.Item("Total Value", i).Value) & "' this wont work for me.can you help me with this query?

Comment: @Randz90 I can help you, but I don't see you posting results of the test I ask you to perform. I don't want to shoot blanks. I want to get to the point

Comment: I tried what u said before.There is no empty field.All the columns return a value.but all values are strings.I want to convert Unitval,Dis,Totval fields into decimal.

Comment: @Randz90 I will update my answer. You have no validation on your data. Really, you don't need convert to decimal to build Insert but you want data to look like decimal string

Comment: I tried your edited code.It seems ok.But because of this line database values getting truncated. Dim orderNum As String = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtOdrNo.Text), "NULL", "'" & itemType.Replace("'", "''") & "'"),value passes for orderNum is same as itemType.I think that is the problem.

Comment: @Randz90 Can you fix it? I am only assuming. You can use other working parts as template and fix the code to your needs. My point here is that you need data validation, conversion of values, etc. Also, parametrization would help as well.

Comment: Yep.I got the point.If you can help me with this code it will highly appreciated.

Comment: @Randz90 I though, I practically placed it in your pocket. What else could be wrong there? My answer had answered your original question and then some more. Why don't you accept it?